# Config nested static folder in Google App Engine Standard - PHP environment

Tags: php, google-app-engine, server, google-cloud-platform, app.yaml

I am having the following file structure:

- public / index.html
- public / css / style.css
- public / images / bg.jpg
- public / app / index.html
- public / app / style.css
- public / app / bundle.js

Once deployed, I can access the `index.html` in root without any problems.

But the `index.html` inside the folder **app** gives 404 error for all **css** and **js** files.

How to configure the app folders assets correctly in my **app.yaml** configuration.

And here is my app.yaml:

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

skip_files: 
- src/
- node_modules/
- ^(.*/)?#.*#
- ^(.*/)?.*~
- ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]
- ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*
- ^(.*/)?\..*

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: public/index.html
  upload: public/index.html

- url: /app/.*
  static_files: public/app/index.html
  upload: public/app/index.html

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: public/\1
  upload: public/(.*)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because according to the handler matching these files you're uploading the `public/app/index.html` instead of the respective files:

```
- url: /app/.*
  static_files: public/app/index.html
  upload: public/app/index.html
```

You should change the handler to upload the respective file, see the  **static_files** row in the [Handlers element](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/appref#handlers_element) table:

```
- url: /app/(.*\.(html|js|css))$
  static_files: public/app/\1
  upload: public/app/.*\.(html|js|css)$
```